# Azure cognitive services text-to-speech service "whispering" style adjustments

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, speech-synthesis, ssml

I am working on a project that requires voice over for videos. I was looking for a free/cheap option for a more natural voice synthesizer options and ran into an article suggesting using Azure TTS service. As of 1/23/2024 it is still true that Azure cognitive services text-to-speech service is free up to 0.5 million characters. Works well for what I'm doing.

I registered in Azure and created a TTS service. I chose *en-US-NancyNeural* as my primary voice as her "whispering" style sounded better than the others.

I would like to make the whispering voice softer than it comes by default. I figured using SSML is the correct approach for altering the TTS result. I was wondering if anyone can share their experience playing with options and making the whispering slower, softer and quieter (more natural). Though default Nancy's whispering is better than the others "she" still whispers very quickly and loudly, lol.

What works well? What does not work? Please, share your experience

Here is the sample of my TTS NodeJS function

```
async function generateSpeechFromText(name, text, tempDirectory) {
  console.log(`Generating speech from text for section: ${name}`)
  const audioFile = `${tempDirectory}/${name}.wav`

  const speechConfig = TTSSdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
    process.env.AZURE_TTS_KEY,
    process.env.AZURE_TTS_REGION
  )
  const audioConfig = TTSSdk.AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput(audioFile)
  speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-NancyNeural"

  let synthesizer = new TTSSdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig)
  const ssml = `<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="en-US">
                  <voice name="${speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName}">
                    <mstts:express-as style="whispering">
                      ${text}
                    </mstts:express-as>
                  </voice>
                </speak>`

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    synthesizer.speakSsmlAsync(
      ssml,
      (result) => {
        if (result.reason === TTSSdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
          console.log("Synthesis finished for: " + name)
          resolve(audioFile)
        } else {
          console.error(
            "Speech synthesis failed for: " + name,
            result.errorDetails
          )
          reject(result.errorDetails)
        }
        synthesizer.close()
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error("Error during synthesis for: " + name, err)
        synthesizer.close()
        reject(err)
      }
    )
  })
}
```

And [here is the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup-structure) to the page that goes over SSML structure and events

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to make the whispering voice softer than it comes by default. I figured using SSML is the correct approach for altering the TTS result.

SSML (Speech Synthesis Markup Language) can make use of various attributes to control the speed, volume, and pitch of the synthesized voice.

- *`<prosody rate="slow">`This is a slow whispering voice.
  `<prosody volume="soft">`This is a soft whispering voice.
  `<prosody pitch="-50%">`This is a lower-pitched whispering voice.*

Configure like below:

```js
const ssml = `<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="en-US">
                  <voice name="${speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName}">
                    <mstts:express-as style="whispering">
                      <prosody rate="slow" volume="soft" pitch="-50%">
                        ${text}
                      </prosody>
                    </mstts:express-as>
                  </voice>
                </speak>`;
```

- I have taken example usage for the case, below is the full code check-out here.

```js
const TTSSdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");

async function generateSpeechFromText(name, text, tempDirectory) {
  console.log(`Generating speech from text for section: ${name}`);
  const audioFile = `${tempDirectory}/${name}.wav`;

  const speechConfig = TTSSdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
    "tts-key",
    "region"
  );
  const audioConfig = TTSSdk.AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput(audioFile);
  speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-NancyNeural";

  let synthesizer = new TTSSdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
  const ssml = `<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="en-US">
                  <voice name="${speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName}">
                    <mstts:express-as style="whispering">
                    //   <prosody rate="slow" volume="soft" pitch="-50%">
                        ${text}
                      </prosody>
                    </mstts:express-as>
                  </voice>
                </speak>`;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    synthesizer.speakSsmlAsync(
      ssml,
      (result) => {
        if (result.reason === TTSSdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
          console.log("Synthesis finished for: " + name);
          resolve(audioFile);
        } else {
          console.error(
            "Speech synthesis failed for: " + name,
            result.errorDetails
          );
          reject(result.errorDetails);
        }
        synthesizer.close();
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error("Error during synthesis for: " + name, err);
        synthesizer.close();
        reject(err);
      }
    );
  });
}

// Example usage
const tempDirectory = "./output";
const sectionName = "example-modified";
const textToSynthesize = "Hello, this is a test whispering voice.";

generateSpeechFromText(sectionName, textToSynthesize, tempDirectory)
  .then((audioFile) => {
    console.log(`Audio file generated: ${audioFile}`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error generating speech:", error);
    console.error("Error during synthesis for: " + name, err);
    console.error("Error stack trace:", err.stack);

  });
```

**Output:**

[image]

*Generated Audio-files:*
[image]

Comment: But have you tried your audio file though? Or you just tried what ChatGPT told you to do? This sounds like a Jigsaw voice from the Saw movies... I did experiment with the volume, it's can make things a bit better, but lowering pitch that much along with the rate is a joke =)

Comment: Have you tried voice options from elevellabs? They got some really nice voice models including whispering ones that are very natural and realistic. I'm trying to achieve same result with Azure synthesizer. My concern is that it's not possible due to limitation of the synthesizer model. Unless I'm wrong and someone has tested something that works.